# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot isn't detecting all the modules for a certain process

Tags: c, winapi, memory

My code is only outputting a few modules in the process, when there are much more. The procID is correct as i've checked in task manager. I would like it to return every single module in the process.

I'm using a C compiler for this. Is this a problem?

```
uintptr_t findModuleAddress (char* name, DWORD procID){
    MODULEENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, procID);
    uintptr_t cModuleAddress = 0;
    Module32First(snapshot,&entry);
    while (Module32Next(snapshot, &entry)){
        printf("%s\n",entry.szModule);
        if (!strcmp(name,entry.szModule)){
            printf("Found module\n");
            cModuleAddress = (uintptr_t)entry.modBaseAddr;
            break;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return cModuleAddress;
}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

Comment: There's a `break;` statement in the loop. If you don't want to break out of a loop early, don't `break;`.

Comment: you need add TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 flag

Comment: You are also skipping the 1st module data provided by `Module32First()`. Use a `do..while` loop instead.